# Unable to upload a json file to vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I am starting out with trying to read in a json file using vb.net. I have a very simple text sample that I stored as a .json file along with very basic code. 
Here is the code:

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\cmannar\sample2.json")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Read()  

    End Sub
End Module
```

My simple text file is called sample2.json and is here:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Jeanette",
  "last_name": "Penddreth",
  "email": "jpenddreth0@census.gov",
  "gender": "Female",
  "ip_address": "26.58.193.2"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Giavani",
  "last_name": "Frediani",
  "email": "gfrediani1@senate.gov",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "229.179.4.212"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "Noell",
  "last_name": "Bea",
  "email": "nbea2@imageshack.us",
  "gender": "Female",
  "ip_address": "180.66.162.255"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "first_name": "Willard",
  "last_name": "Valek",
  "email": "wvalek3@vk.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "67.76.188.26"
}]
```

It compiles fine and there are no errors, but it does not print out my .json file. It stays as a blank screen. 
If someone could show me where I went wrong, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't print the file, you just print an empty line:

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

If you want to print the file contents, you need to tell Console.WriteLine *what* you want to print:

```
Console.WriteLine(json)
```

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!